# Why are CVS branch numbers even?

Tags: version-control, cvs

I'm interested in why the branch numbers for CVS are even? E.g. 1.2.0.2. What is 1.2.0.1 used for? Is it used by CVS internally?

Comment: what's your 2nd question about? "the web"? do you mean StackOverflow? If so the reason is self-explanatory.  You are possibly writing too little

Comment: Revision numbers end in both odd and even numbers. Why do you think they always end in even numbers?

Comment: @BurhanAli please note that I meant "branch number" instead of "revision number".

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation detail of CVS. There is some magic about the version numbers involved (look at [rcs.h](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/ccvs/src/rcs.h?view=annotate&root=cvs#l223) and [rcs.c](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/ccvs/src/rcs.c?view=annotate&root=cvs#l2477) for details).